# TurtleControlNode.call_set_pen_service() missing 4 required positional arguments

Tags: ros2, python, rosservice

I have been trying to learn ROS2 humble and was studying about service.
I have create a Node with pub and sub with a service.
pub - for controlling turtle in turtlesim,
sub - for current position of turtle,
service - for changing the color of line if turtle is on the right side for left

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import rclpy
from rclpy.node import Node
from geometry_msgs.msg import Twist
from turtlesim.msg import Pose
from turtlesim.srv import SetPen
from functools import partial

class TurtleControlNode(Node):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__("control_turtle")
        self.previous_x_ = 0
        self.cmd_vel_pub_ = self.create_publisher(Twist,"/turtle1/cmd_vel", 10)
        self.pose_subscriber_ = self.create_subscription(Pose, "/turtle1/pose", self.control_callback, 10)

    def control_callback(self,pose:Pose):
        msg = Twist()
        if pose.x > 9.0 or pose.x < 2.0 or pose.y > 9.0 or pose.y < 2.0:
            msg.linear.x = 1.0
            msg.angular.z =0.9
        else:
            msg.linear.x = 5.0
            msg.angular.z = 0.0
        self.cmd_vel_pub_.publish(msg)

        if pose.x > 5.5 and self.previous_x_ <= 5.5:
            self.previous_x_ = pose.x
            self.get_logger().info("Set color to red")
            self.call_set_pen_service(255, 0, 0, 3, 0)
        elif pose.x <= 5.5 and self.previous_x_ > 5.5:
            self.previous_x_ = pose.x
            self.get_logger().info("set color to green")
            self.call_set_pen_service(0, 255, 0, 3, 0)

    def call_set_pen_service(self, r,g,b,width,off):
        client = self.create_client(SetPen,"/turtle1/set_pen")
        while not client.wait_for_service(1.0):
            self.get_logger().wait("waiting for service")
        
        request = SetPen.Request()
        request.r = r
        request.g = g
        request.b = b
        request.width = width
        request.off = off

        future = client.call_async(request)
        future.add_done_callback(partial(self.call_set_pen_service))

    def callback_set_pen(self, future):
        try:
            response = future.result()
            #self.get_logger().info(response)
        except Exception as e:
            self.logger().error("service: %r" % (e,))


def main(args=None):
    rclpy.init(args=args)
    node = TurtleControlNode()
    rclpy.spin(node)
    rclpy.shutdown()
```

I am encountering the error

```
    [INFO] [1701598860.044286099] [control_turtle]: Set color to red
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/red/ros2_ws/install/my_robot_controller/lib/my_robot_controller/TurCont", line 33, in <module>
    sys.exit(load_entry_point('my-robot-controller==0.0.0', 'console_scripts', 'TurCont')())
File "/home/red/ros2_ws/install/my_robot_controller/lib/python3.10/site-packages/my_robot_controller/turtle_controller.py", line 61, in main
    rclpy.spin(node)
File "/opt/ros/humble/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/rclpy/__init__.py", line 222, in spin
    executor.spin_once()
File "/opt/ros/humble/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/rclpy/executors.py", line 739, in spin_once
    self._spin_once_impl(timeout_sec)
File "/opt/ros/humble/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/rclpy/executors.py", line 736, in _spin_once_impl
    raise handler.exception()
File "/opt/ros/humble/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/rclpy/task.py", line 251, in __call__
    self.set_result(self._handler(*self._args, **self._kwargs))
TypeError: TurtleControlNode.call_set_pen_service() missing 4 required positional arguments: 'g', 'b', 'width', and 'off'
[ros2run]: Process exited with failure 1
```

but I am calling the function with all the attributes.
In turtlesim turtle is moving in left direction with red line but its crashing the node and turtle is stuck on the left window border.